# Downstream from 20amp GFCI

Tags: electrical

I have a 20 amp GFCI outlet in my basement bathroom finish. I will have a 2nd outlet downstream in the same junction box. Do I need to use 12/2 for this or will 14/2 work?

Comment: GFCIs are NOT fuses.  They are the very opposite of fuses; a 15A GFCI is *specifically UL-listed* for 20A pass-through.

Answer (score 6):

The breaker is 20A, it HAS to be 12 Gauge. No 14 gauge anywhere on a 20A circuit, and the bathroom circuit has to be 20A.